# Swift DateIntervalFormatter: keep dates out of the string even if interval spans multiple days

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I am trying to format a time interval. I want a result that looks like this:

```
10:45 - 12:00 AM
```

I can get very close to this using `DateInvervalFormatter`:

```
let cal = Calendar.current
let formatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .none
formatter.timeStyle = .short
let start = Date()
let end = cal.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: start)
formatter.string(from: DateInterval(start: start, end: end!))
```

The above (in the en_US locale) will produce an output such as:

```
5:27 – 6:27 PM
```

Looks good right? However, this does not work if the two dates in the interval are on different days. For example:

```
let formatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .none
formatter.timeStyle = .short
let startComponents = DateComponents(year: 2020, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 23, minute: 45)
let start = cal.date(from: startComponents)
let end = cal.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: start!)
formatter.string(from: DateInterval(start: start!, end: end!))
```

Despite setting `dateStyle` to `.none`, the string produced in the above example (in the en_US locale) is:

```
1/1/2020, 11:45 PM – 1/2/2020, 12:45 AM
```

What I want is:

```
11:45 PM – 12:45 AM
```

How can I get this? I know I could use a `DateFormatter` to format each date (start and end) into just a time, and then append the two strings together with a hyphen (`-`) in the middle, but this is not necessarily localization-friendly.

Comment: I don't get what's wrong about the localization when using the date formatter approach.

Comment: @LeoDabus Maybe there is nothing wrong with using DateFormatter, but I am certainly not an expert in all locales and assume there may be some that would not use a hyphen. Apple's done all the hard localization work in DateIntervalFormatter and I'd like to tap into that.

Comment: Well I don’t think they will display a date interval of two different dates with time only

Comment: Perhaps! But maybe there is a way - hence my question. It's strange that they still display dates given a `dateStyle` of `.none`... That seems like it would be the logical way to achieve what I want.

Comment: I would argue that what you get now is the logic way to do it because without the dates it would be impossible to interpret the information correctly

Comment: Airlines will use a target destination's time zone to display layover times as it would be very confusing to display an interval spanning over two zones. If the interval spans over days, it's typically in this fashion: `11:45 PM – 12:45 AM`.  That said, I think DateFormatter is a good approach depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, all. @JoakimDanielson, I agree that if the two dates span more than 12 hours, it would be strange to leave out the dates. However something like `11:45 PM - 12:45 AM`, where the difference between the two dates is just an hour, is pretty easy to interpret. Consider a nightclub, for example. It's clear what 10 PM - 2 AM means, without specifying dates.

Comment: That is a very specific example and yes everybody understands it since nightclubs are not open during the day so the closing time can only be after midnight the next day. And since you have such a specific requirement you need a specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up with is:

```swift
extension Date {
    
    func formatTimeInterval(
        to: Date,
        timeZone: TimeZone = .autoupdatingCurrent
    ) -> String {
        
        let formatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = timeZone
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        formatter.dateStyle = .none
        
        // we need to manually strip any "date" metadata, because for some locales,
        // even if we set `formatter.dateStyle = .none`, if the dates are in two different days
        // we will still get the date information in the end result (e.g. for the US locale)
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let fromComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: self)
        let toComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: to)
        let fromDate = calendar.date(from: fromComponents)!
        let toDate = calendar.date(from: toComponents)!
        return formatter.string(from: fromDate, to: toDate)
    }
}
```

However, if the interval dates are in different months (say 31st August - 1 September), it adds a date starting at year 1, something like

`1/1/1, 11:45 PM – 1/2/1, 12:45 AM`

No clean solution to this still...